# Exclude files that end with a certain file extension

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

I would like to get all files in, say, the working directory, excluding files that, for example, end with `.pl`. So, `test.pl` should be excluded but not `test.txt` or `test.xyz`

The expression `glob(".* *")` matches all the files in a working directory and seems to be working well. Except for the part of excluding files that end with `.pl`. I have tried several expression including `*(?!.pl),` but none seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

A common way is to use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to exclude items in a list:

```
my @files = grep { !/\.pl$/ } glob(".* *");
```